# jQuery change event only triggers in one out of three elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problem. My jQuery change event should activate everytime I change one of the elements shown in my HTML code with the class "validation".

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="controls form-inline">
    <label for="ff_elem295" id="bfLabel295" class="control-label"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> <?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_DIRECCION'); ?></label>
    <input type="text" id="ff_elem295" value="<?php echo $post['direccion'] ? $post['direccion'] : "";?>" name="direccion" class="validation ff_elem inputbox required" required="required">
</div>

<div class="controls form-inline">
    <label for="ff_elem305" id="bfLabel305" class="control-label"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> <?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_PROV'); ?></label>

    <span id="idPro" data-attr='class="validation required" required="required"'></span>
        <select id="id_provincia" name="id_provincia">
                <option  value="" selected="selected"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_SELECT_PROVINCIAS');?></option>
        </select>   
</div>

<div class="controls form-inline">
    <label for="ff_elem306" id="bfLabel306" class="control-label"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> <?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_MUNI'); ?></label>

    <span id="idMun" data-attr='class="validation required" required="required"'></span>
        <select id="id_municipio" name="id_municipio">
            <option  value="" selected="selected"><?php echo JText::_('COM_CSTUDOMUS_SELECT_MUNICIPIOS');?></option>
        </select>
</div>
```

The event **only triggers** when you write in the input box and it never triggers when you change country or state/province.

**JS CODE**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var direccion="";
    var flag = false;
    jQuery(".validation").change(function () {
        flag = true;
        alert("change");
        jQuery(".validation").each(function () {
            if (jQuery(this).val().trim() == "") {
                flag = false;
            }
        });
        if (flag==true) {
            alert("true");
            var calle = jQuery("#ff_elem295").val();
            var municipio = jQuery("#id_municipio option:selected").text();
            var provincia = jQuery("#id_provincia option:selected").text();             

            direccion = calle +","+ municipio +","+ provincia;
            direccion = direccion.replace(/\s/g,'+');

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "index.php?option=com_cstudomus&controller=saloninmobiliarios&task=calcularDistancias",
                data : {direccion : direccion}
            }).done(function(data){
                var sitios = data.split(',');
                    jQuery("#ff_elem245").val(sitios[7]); //Supermercado
                    jQuery("#ff_elem251").val(sitios[0]); //Centro Comercial
                    jQuery("#ff_elem252").val(sitios[1]); //Colegio
                    jQuery("#ff_elem254").val(sitios[4]); //Centro Ciudad
                    jQuery("#ff_elem259").val(sitios[5]); //Autobús
                    jQuery("#ff_elem261").val(sitios[3]); //Metro
                    jQuery("#ff_elem263").val(sitios[2]); //Aeropuerto
                    jQuery("#ff_elem267").val(sitios[6]); //Ambulatorio
            });
        }       
    });
});
```

I believe the issue is that the class "validation" is assigned to the select field **after** you choose the country. The same thing happens to city. It seems that the change event points to the first object which is already destroyed even though its created afterwards (it still points to the previous one).

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have tried substituting the class "validation" for each id of these fields in the change event and the same problem ocurrs

Comment: Try `jQuery(document).on('change', '.validation', function () {...`

Comment: @adeneo works perfect! haha, put it up as an anwser please so I can vote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers only work on the elements that match the selector at the time the event handler is bound. If you're going to change the class later and expect the event handler to work, you'll have to delegate it to a parent element.

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '.validation', function () {

    // code here

});
```

You should pick a parent element that is closer to limit the collection, something like

```
jQuery('.controls').on('change', '.validation', function () { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me inside of a Dcocument.ready

```
$(document).on('change', '.classname', function () {
```

}